# 8 bit checksum with wraparound in C

Tags: c, networking, checksum

I've made an 8 bit checksum function, but the sums don't wraparound, by that I mean that overflow carries on the left are not added back on the right. How can I achieve this?

```
unsigned char checksum(unsigned char message[], int nBytes) 
{
    unsigned char sum = 0;

    while (nBytes-- > 0)
    {
        sum += *(message++);
    }

    return (~sum);
}
```

For example, when two bytes are added, this is the kind of wraparound I am trying to achieve:

```
 1001 1100
+1100 0010
------------
 0101 1111 (sum)
 1010 0000 Checksum (1's complement)
```

Comment: `"overflow carries on the left are not added back on the right"` that is not how overflow or wraparound generally works.

Comment: calculation of a checksum normally ignores carries/overflows.  Are you sure you want to add the overflow back into the product?

Comment: I'm controlling both sender and receiver so it works out. I'm just following a specification, but it is good to know what the standard is for future notice, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an unusual requirement, but this should do the trick (with no claim made for efficiency):

```
unsigned char checksum(unsigned char message[], int nBytes) 
{
    unsigned char sum = 0;

    while (nBytes-- > 0)
    {
        int carry = (sum + *message > 255) ? 1 : 0;
        sum += *(message++) + carry;
    }

    return (~sum);
}
```

The arithmetic and comparison is done using `int` because of the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: For the word "sugar", I calculated looking at an ASCII table:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii, 115 + 117 + 103 + 97 + 114 which with the carry of 1 results in interim sums of 232, then 335+1, 433+1, 548+1 = 549 final which is 3 greater than just summing 546.  So when the subtotal exceeds the 8 bit representation possible, you're adding 1 but it seems like I should be adding 256 instead.

Comment: Read that unsigned is 0 to 255 and signed is -127 to 127.

Comment: The range for unsigned 8-bit `char` is 0..255.  The range for signed 8-bit `char` depends on whether you have sign-and-magnitude, one’s complement or two’s complement arithmetic. With one’s complement and sign-and-magnitude, there are two representations for zero (positive and negative) and the range is indeed -127 to +127.  For two’s complement, there is an asymmetry in the range: -128 to +127 (and a single representation for zero). You’re unlikely to come across a machine that does not use two’s complement arithmetic.